# How to highlight text and change the height and position in css?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering: how can I highlight text and change the height of the highlight?
This is what I got:

```css
.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(110deg, #005fed, #00bbff);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <span class="highlight">World</span></h1>
```

Now, for big font-sizes I'd like to have the "highlight" less high than the text, and this code works fine, but I can't position it to the center of the text. This is the result:
[click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2pWX.png)

Now, how can i center that background to the height of the line?

I'd like to use the percentage of the line-height, so it can be more responsive too, but with percentage this doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you want us to do...you have two different questions: "how can I highlight text and change the height of the highlight?" and "how can i center that background to the height of the line?". How to highlight a word and increase the length of the highlight. You have done that already. Just increase the `height` in `.hightlight` to cover the whole word. now, to center the background of the height of the line, I am assuming just increase the height of the highlight until it looks center....If I am wrong please example and why and where. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `background` to achieve this.

```css
.highlight {
  /*                                                        ↓ y position */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #005fed, #00bbff) 0 25% / 100% 10px no-repeat;
  /*                                                                    ↑ line height */
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <span class="highlight">Kitty</span></h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change styles to this:

```css
.highlight{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(110deg, #005fed, #00bbff);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello <span class="highlight">World</span></h1>
```

Comment: I don't want the height to be auto, i'd like to have an highlight less high than the line-height, but i can't center it as you can see in the screenshot :)

Comment: @FedericoVisioli Done :)